# RequireJS modyfing array inside module from another module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have following module named maps2 in require JS:

```
define([], function(){

    var z = [];

    function changeZ(){
        z = [1,2,3];
        console.log(z);
    }

    return {

        z: z,
        changeZ: changeZ
    }
});
```

and main file:

```
requirejs(['maps2'], function(maps2){

    console.log(maps2.z);
    maps2.changeZ();
    console.log(maps2.z);
});
```

Here is the problem: I was expecting result like:

```
[]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

However instead I got result:

```
[]
[1,2,3]
[]
```

I'm a bit confused. Why third console.log produced `[]` instead of modified `z` array after calling `changeZ` function?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially not different from doing:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
b = [1, 2, 3];
```

Why should the value of `a` be changed after `b = [1, 2, 3]`?? In your code, the field `z` of the return value of your module is initialized from the variable `z` but if you assign to the variable `z`, why should the value of the field be changed?

If you want `changeZ` to affect the value returned from you module, you could do something like this:

```
define([], function(){
    var exports = {
        z: [],
        changeZ: changeZ
    };

    function changeZ(){
        exports.z = [1,2,3];
        console.log(exports.z);
    }

    return exports;
});
```

Comment: I apologize, but I don't understand. I don't see analogy from your example - I did not created new variable (well probably somewhere I did, but I don't see where), all the time I'm operating on z variable from maps2 module. Could you please provide a little more detailed answer?